# How to disable basic http auth of jenkins

Tags: jenkins

My jenkins version: 1.608, it running behind nginx.

I just installed jenkins from portage, and go to `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure Global Security` > enable `Enable security` > choose `Jenkins’ own user database` > enable `Allow users to sign up` > click `Save` button

Then page refreshed, jenkins ask me to login with basic http authentication, but I haven't added any user, and I can not access the signup page.

I can disable `useSecurity` in `/var/lib/jenkins/home/config.xml`, but I want to use `Jenkins’ own user database`.

And I never found `Manage Users` in `Manage Jenkins` page.

Comment: Havr you tried removing authorizationStrategy and securityRealm in the same config? Without setting useSecurity to false.

Comment: @Stanjer Awesome! The issue resolved! So much thanks! Is there any way to mark your comment become answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove authorizationStrategy and securityRealm in config.xml. Leave "useSecurity" as "true".

Comment: After I done as your said, jenkins haven't `Enable security`,  I need to enable the setting again, then it works. This comment is a supplement.

Answer (score 0):

I helped in the file /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/security/SecurityFilters.groovy comment out the block

```
bean(BasicHeaderProcessor) {
            // if basic authentication fails (which only happens incorrect basic auth credential is sent),
            // respond with 401 with basic auth request, instead of redirecting the user to the login page,
            // since users of basic auth tends to be a program and won't see the redirection to the form
            // page as a failure
             authenticationEntryPoint = bean(BasicProcessingFilterEntryPoint) {
                realmName = "Jenkins"
            }
        },
```